# Another strange compiler error: calling a templated function which gives undefined referenes

Tags: c++, function, templates, dictionary

So far, so good. However, a few issues have arisen.

First and foremost, is that when I call the following:

```
const bool bppExists = CheckMapForExistingEntry< std::string, int >( mConfigValues, "bpp" );
```

I get the following:

```
error: undefined reference to `bool CheckMapForExistingEntry<std::string, int>(std::map<std::string, int, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > > const&, std::string const&)'
```

There are three other instances of where this is happening. The function looks as follows:

**Declaration**

```
template < class Key, class Value >
bool CheckMapForExistingEntry( const std::map< Key, Value >& map, const std::string& key );
```

**Definition**

```
template < class Key, class Value >
bool CheckMapForExistingEntry( const std::map< Key, Value >& map, const std::string& key )
{

    typename std::map< Key, Value >::iterator it = map.lower_bound( key );

    bool keyExists = ( it != map.end && !( map.key_comp() ( key, it->first ) ) );

    if ( keyExists )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thus, what is happening here? I have the header file included which contains the declaration of the function, and yet it still doesn't work. According to [this](http://ideone.com/lcsQB), I'm supposed to leave out the value of the template argument and just pass the `key_type`, however that refuses to work as well.

For example:

```
CheckMapForExistingEntry< std::string >( someMap, "somekey" ); //error
```

Comment: source file; declaration is in header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just easily split the declaration and the definition of templates between header and source file; thus templates are usually defined in headers. See e.g. [*"Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Also you don't need to explicitly provide any type parameters in this case:

```
CheckMapForExistingEntry(m, "x");
```

The types `Key` and `Value` can be automatically deduced from the `map` type.

Note that your function can be significantly shortened, e.g.:

```
template < class Key, class Value >
bool contains(const std::map<Key, Value>& map, const std::string& key) {
    return map.find(key) != map.end();
}
```

Additionally you could generalize the type of the `key` parameter, making the function more reusable.

Comment: The original code only requires that the search string can be compared with keys, not that it can be converted to the key type.

Comment: @Ben: But `lower_bound()` requires a `key_type` as a parameter?

Comment: You're right of course.  `std::lower_bound` accepts any comparable value, but the `map` member function requires exactly the key type.